# Keep the server open when client disconnect Python

Tags: python, sockets, client

I'm currently working on a project and I need to use socket (python). My problem is :
- When the client disconnect, my server disconnect too. But I don't want this. I want the server to stay alive all the time, how can I do that ?

If I close the client I would like the server to keep alive

Here is my code :

Client :

```
import socket

hote = "localhost"
port = 12800

connexion_avec_serveur = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
connexion_avec_serveur.connect((hote, port))
print("Established {}".format(port))

msg_a_envoyer = b""
while msg_a_envoyer != b"fin":
    msg_a_envoyer = input("> ")
    msg_a_envoyer = msg_a_envoyer.encode()
    connexion_avec_serveur.send(msg_a_envoyer)
    msg_recu = connexion_avec_serveur.recv(1024)
    print(msg_recu.decode())

print("Close connection")
connexion_avec_serveur.close()
```

Server :

```
import socket
import select

hote = ''
port = 12800

connexion_principale = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
connexion_principale.bind((hote, port))
connexion_principale.listen(5)
print("rece {}".format(port))

serveur_lance = True
clients_connectes = []
while serveur_lance:
    connexions_demandees, wlist, xlist = select.select([connexion_principale],
        [], [], 0.05)

    for connexion in connexions_demandees:
        connexion_avec_client, infos_connexion = connexion.accept()
        clients_connectes.append(connexion_avec_client)

    clients_a_lire = []
    try:
        clients_a_lire, wlist, xlist = select.select(clients_connectes,
                [], [], 0.05)
    except select.error:
        pass
    else:
        for client in clients_a_lire:
            msg_recu = client.recv(1024)
            msg_recu = msg_recu.decode()
            print("Recu {}".format(msg_recu))
            client.send(b"5 / 5")
            if msg_recu == "fin":
                serveur_lance = False
```

Excuse my english.

Thanks for your help

Comment: It looks like the server listening on port 12800 *does* stay alive.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect it's not when the client disconnects, as such, but when the client sends `"fin"`. That's when the client's loop stops, and also when the server's loop stops.  The only thing in the code you've posted that changes the value of `serveur_lance` is when the client sends `"fin"`:

```
while serveur_lance:
...
        if msg_recu == "fin":
            serveur_lance = False
```

So the moment someone types `fin` into the client, the server will also get the command to stop.

Instead of changing the value of `serveur_lance` in your server code, you probably want to close that specific connection and remove it from the `clients_connectes` list.